# css issue maybe js issue on magento site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento

Issue: https://www.mirabella.com/find-your-style/mirabellaclothing/mirabellagear/mirabella-white-sweatshirt.html

this is what happens when we upload a product with with attributes. It seems to be a position issue. But i have tried everything I can think of to correct the issue. If I remove the position attribute it looks fine except some of the text is incorrectly positioned. Actually everything i have tried has not corrected the text position. thanks

Comment: If my answer is correct please mark as correct, or if you found a better solution, please post it so we all can share and learn.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "float:left;" attribute from the style:

```
.product-view .product-img-box {
    /* float: left; */
    width: 400px;
}
```

I would also force the "a.selectBox" (which represents the select control) to be of 100% width to make it fully responsive.